# Is there some drink like panaché available in the Netherlands?

Tags: substitutions

Hi I remember summers around 2006 where we bought  Panaché at our local Lidl and a lot of people liked it. It's a soda drink with a little bit of beer. it looks like this:

[image: panache]

Of course there is [Shandy](https://www.ah.nl/producten/product/wi134037/royal-club-shandy) and [Radler](https://www.ah.nl/producten2/product/wi232950/grolsch-radler-citroen), but I don't find them quite the same.

Comment: You can do your own panaché of course.  Diluting syrup of your taste with beer of the lager type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Panache [is available](https://www.facebook.com/lepanachebeverages/posts/2215556705430889).

It seems to be similar to Shandy, or "[Sneeuwwitje](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shandy)" in Dutch.

Comment: Oh great you found a way to buy it directly from the manufacturer. Funny you buy it via whatsapp (sound a little scammy, but let's give it a try)!

Comment: No, no. I have never bought anything from them. I live in Spain. It was just a search.